# Mosfet load control - different design compared

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design

i've seen in a forum this design (Circuit 1) to drive a load using mosfet, i'm wondering in which differs from the "well-known" MCU mosfet driven loads like the second one in the image below (Circuit 2)?

[image]

What are advantages/drawbacks on using the first design over the second?

Comment: The first design relies on an unknown signal called "ESP GPIO32" and so comparisons cannot be made just on that basis alone. The second circuit uses a much more powerful MOSFET whereas the 2N7002 is weak in comparison. The two circuits are largely incompatible.

Comment: Yes i know that are not comparable in a technical aspect, i was considering only design difference between the two circuits

Comment: Design differences **are** a technical aspect so, realistically I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Maybe i have to detail more: consider the two mosfet driving method, in which they differs? when i might use one instead the other one?

Comment: One drives a lamp (and uses an extra line called "ESP GPIO32") and the other drives a relay - the two circuits are incompatible. This is beginning to look like an XY question. Why don't you state what you require to happen and forget about the circuits - let others make suggestions on how to accomplish what you want to happen.

Comment: You're right, i'm modifying the post with the two circuit, basically, my intention is to drive a secondary circuit using an ESP32 GPIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answered after the OP modified the question

In both designs, the object is to apply sufficient voltage between gate and source to properly turn the MOSFET on and then, when turning the MOSFET off, have 0 volts between gate and source. Both designs can do this providing the load impedance is quite high. This is because of the choice of MOSFET being a 2N7002: -

[image]

With only 3.3 volts as the maximum gate-source drive voltage, the 2N7002 has a pretty poor on-characteristic for loads that might take in excess of 100 mA. As can be seen in the characteristic above with a load current of about 100 mA, the voltage dropped will be at best around 0.7 volts (orange circle) and possibly 1 or 2 volts for non-typical devices.

However, if the 2N7002 were assumed to be "suitable" (not proven by any means), the only thing to consider is that circuit 1 has to be able to "sink" the load current when its signal goes low - this might be a showstopper in many situations so, how much current can the "DIGITAL_IN" signal sink? If it can sink 100 mA without much volt drop then it's probably OK.

Comment: So maybe replacing the 2n7002 with FDV303N it's better and more "safe" with load of 500mA?

Comment: Please link the data sheet so I can take a look and explain.

Comment: Here you go: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1810301530_ON-Semiconductor-FDV303N_C80498.pdf

Comment: Look at figure 1  - it tells you that at 500 mA the volt drop across the MOSFET is about 0.2 volts - is that good enough? Only you can say.

Comment: Well i think that this voltage drop it will be so high: i need to power up a sub-circuit with an STM32 and RS232 tranciever...can you have some advices about what mosfet i can use?

Comment: Not without knowing what volt drop you can tolerate - look for MOSFETs explicitly sold as logic level types with low \$R_{DS(ON)}\$. Knowing \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ and knowing 500 mA, you can calculate the volt drop but, it has to be able to work effectively with a gate drive voltage on only 3.3 volts so familiarize yourself with the graph in my answer because every single MOSFET will have a similar graph and that graphs has the information. I don't have a MOSFET part number off the top of my head.

Comment: Yes i have to familiarize with those graphs, i've tried to better understood that and maybe this is a good one, right? https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1908282219_Pingjingsemi-PJM2302NSA-S_C411710.pdf

Comment: How can I judge - my opening words in my last comment were "Not without knowing what volt drop you can tolerate" - this means I cannot judge without YOU explicitly stating what volt drop you can tolerate. I can't guess that for you. I've provided the ammo and the gun, you need to provide the target.

Comment: The only strict parameter that i need to respect is related to the serial levels, i'm using max232 to communicate with other devices, so, i need to power up "safely" the max232

Comment: That doesn't give me a number. Have you looked at that data sheet? Have you tried to figure out what volt drop you get when 500 mA is flowing - this is the important thing - what happens if I tell you that the volt drop is 0.2 volts? Would you then say this is too much and go away and find another MOSFET and ask me to look at the graph again and, if it still turns out to be not good enough, where does this spiral of non-learning end? Grasp the thorn. Get used to that graph. Learn.

Answer (score 1):

(note, the edits have rendered comments and previous answers not very relevant)

The first circuit has voltage gain, but no current gain. Assuming a "load" is connected between pins 1 and 4, the load will see 0V/(almost) 5V but all the load current must be switched by the MCU port pin. When the MCU pin is low the load has 5V across it.

The second circuit has both voltage gain and current gain. Assuming the same connections as above, the load will also see 0V/(closer to)5V and all the load current is switched by the MOSFET, the MCU port pin only sees a brief pulse. When the MCU pin is high the load has 5V across it.

Comment: So, between the two schematic what you recommend?

Comment: Use the one that fits your application better.

Comment: I think that the typical MOSFET usage of driving high currents will go for the second design...so what is the meaning of using the first design?

Comment: If you want no inversion and have a light load. For example, for level-shifting on an I2C bus from 3.3V to 5V.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose that it can be used also to drive (for example) an enable pin that needs 5V reference...so, light loads